# Cascade delete in parent-child using tableadaptermanager.updateall

Tags: ado.net, master-detail, bindingsource, tableadapter

I have two `datagridview`, one shows parent records and the other it's child records.

I defined into the dataset the relation and foreign key constraint with cascade update and delete rule and hierarchical update set to true.

I want to delete a record on the parent `datagridview` and delete it's child records.
Below my code:

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Sicuro", "Attenzione", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        try
        {
            //parent table
            pianoDiInterventoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();

            //child table
            pianoInterventoServiziBindingSource.EndEdit();

            pianoDiInterventoBindingSource.EndEdit();
            tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.archivioDataSet);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            this.pianoDiInterventoTableAdapter.Fill(this.archivioDataSet.PianoDiIntervento);
            this.pianoInterventoServiziTableAdapter.Fill(this.archivioDataSet.PianoInterventoServizi);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to delete parent record but childs records were not, so I after have a `constraintexception error`.

Why is this?